# network driver for laptop

Tags: windows, drivers

I have gotten into a mess as I bought a new laptop Dell Inspiron N5010 and the driver cd in it does not contain the driver for lan. This is strange but then I asked my friend and installed the same driver he had and it does works but the problem is that whenever I connect for the first time I am unable to connect.

I always have to disable and reenable Realtek PCI driver through device manager and then it connects.

What solutions do I have with and can I find my actual drivers through any way ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to locate the service tag on your machine and enter it at dell.com in the drivers section, that should give you all available drivers for your laptop